# Why is my result a cross product when I am doing inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, cross-product

I would like to display details of student based on their class and academic year
here is what i used to achieve the same:

```
SELECT
  a1.fk_stu_id,
  b.stu_fname,
  c.class_name,
  d.section_code,
  e.acad_year
FROM
  tbl_stu_class a1
 JOIN
  tbl_stu_details b
ON
  (b.pk_stu_id = a1.fk_stu_id),
  list_class c
 JOIN
  tbl_stu_class a2
ON
  c.pk_class_id = a2.fk_class_id,
  list_sections d
 JOIN
  tbl_stu_class a3
ON
  d.pk_section_id = a3.fk_section_id,
  list_acad_years e
 JOIN
  tbl_stu_class a4
ON
  e.pk_acad_year_id = a4.fk_year_id
WHERE
  c.class_name = '10';
```

but this returns the cross product of academic years for each student...
here is the output of the above query:

```
 fk_stu_id  stu_fname   class_name  section_code    acad_year   
      1       sss            10         A             2019
      2     Second           10         A             2019
      1       sss            10         A             2017
      2     Second           10         A             2017
```

Result expected :

```
fk_stu_id   stu_fname   class_name  section_code    acad_year   
      1       sss            10         A             2019
      2     Second           10         B             2017
```

can someone explain why is it so? how do i solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the result you're trying to get?

Comment: What type of SQL is this? I don't understand your JOIN syntax with the comma..

Comment: as i have to fetch details from different tables the query resulted this way....

Comment: I highly suggest not using that syntax. Just join all the tables you need in a regular fashion. That's probably what's causing the issue

Comment: @JoePhillips could you just elaborate and what is the error in the above query could you explain please ? as i am new to this it would be of great help

Comment: @YashParekh what database is it?

Comment: @JoePhillips MYSQL

Comment: Tables joined by commas are cross joins.That is the problem most certainly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your query reformatted to see what's going on.

```
SELECT
  a1.fk_stu_id,
  b.stu_fname,
  c.class_name,
  d.section_code,
  e.acad_year
FROM
  tbl_stu_class a1  JOIN tbl_stu_details b ON (b.pk_stu_id = a1.fk_stu_id)
, list_class c      JOIN tbl_stu_class a2  ON c.pk_class_id = a2.fk_class_id
, list_sections d   JOIN tbl_stu_class a3  ON d.pk_section_id = a3.fk_section_id
, list_acad_years e JOIN tbl_stu_class a4  ON e.pk_acad_year_id = a4.fk_year_id

WHERE
  c.class_name = '10';
```

You have 4 separate JOIN sections, with commas between them. So you get a cross product of these 4 sections.

Don't use commas, use JOINs between all tables.

Since `tbl_stu_class` is in all sections, `class_id` is probably the way to join those sections together.

But actually, I think you don't need those extra instances `a2 .. a4` at all. Can't really tell without seeing your table schemas and data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    a.fk_stu_id,
    b.stu_fname,
    c.class_name,
    d.section_code,
    e.acad_year
FROM
    tbl_stu_class a
JOIN
    tbl_stu_details b
ON
    b.pk_stu_id = a.fk_stu_id
JOIN
    list_class c
ON
    c.pk_class_id = a.fk_class_id
JOIN
    list_sections d
ON
    d.pk_section_id = a.fk_section_id
JOIN
    list_acad_years e
ON
    e.pk_acad_year_id = a.fk_year_id
WHERE
    c.class_name = '10';
```